# Html Agility Pack - how to select correct span class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find lowest price on Amazon pages. Let's use this url as an example:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9963BB#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=E999-4701&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AE999-4701
```

I want to find the lowest price ... the number to the right of "new from".

Here's what I have tried:

```
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\AmazonUrls.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var document = webGet.Load(item);
                var lowestPrice = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='subPrice']");
                if (lowestPrice != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lowestPrice);                
                }

            }           
        }
```

I'm not getting any result. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for nodes with an `id` of subPrice, but it is in fact `class` that has subPrice:

```
<span class="subPrice">
        <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B001BA0W06/ref=sr_1_6_olp?ie=UTF8&qid=1334090832&sr=8-6&condition=new">5 new</a>
    from <span class="price">$245.90</span></span>
```

so,

```
var lowestPrice = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='subPrice']");
```

should get you what you want. However, the example page that you give has several nodes that match that pattern, so you problem want to select multiple nodes and then loop through them to decide which has the lowest privce.

Comment: I added .InnerText after your suggestion and it returned "2 new from $5.00". I can handle it from there. Thanks :)

Comment: but program is crashing after returning one result. Maybe this is not the right thread to solve that issue in, but does anyone know why the foreach would die after one iteration?

Comment: With what exception is it crashing?

Comment: system.NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You'll probably have to show the code that populates list in order to get any help with that.

Comment: ```("//span[contains(@class, 'subPrice')]");``` if the tag has more than one class.