# HTML Agility pack - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, html, xamarin.forms

I am using HTML Agility pack in Xamarin and I keep getting the following error. `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The error is coming from the foreach loop and I saw that the `nodes` variable was `null`, but I don't know why. It is probably because my node selection is not right, but I don't how to fix it as I already tried different selections.

```
string source = getSource(url);
if (source == "") return;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='events']");

var nodeText = "";

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    nodeText += node.InnerText;
}
lbl_geheel.Text = nodeText;
```

So I guess `("//div[@id='events']")` is not right.

This is the HTML code that I am scraping:

```
<div id="events" class="">
```

From the following page: https://www.espn.in/football/scoreboard

Comment: Does it have a way to select a **single** node perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130244/htmlagilitypack-how-to-get-the-tag-by-id

Comment: @mjwills like this? `string source = getSource(url);
                if (source == "") return;

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(source);

                HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='events']");

             
                lbl_geheel.Text = node.InnerText;` Still getting the same error.

Comment: `HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.espn.in/football/scoreboard");
            HtmlNode node = docHtml.GetElementbyId("events");
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
            Console.ReadLine();` works fine. _Note it outputs blank, but that is to be expected._

Comment: @mjwills I don't understand why it's empty, but I will read the post. Why did my original code returned `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and your code didn't?

Comment: Because there was an issue in your selector. I am not _exactly_ sure what the issue was - but I know that if you have an id then using `GetElementById` is much simpler.

Comment: @mjwills Alright. However, this particular id is not actually something I really needed. I just used this as example. Sometimes I need something that has no id, but has a class for example or a data-type. Let's say I want the text from `<span class="test">Text</span>` then I cannot use `GetElementById`. How would I approach this?

Comment: You'll need to write a new question for that, alas. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096253/34092 is the likely duplicate for it. Found by Googling for `html agility pack search for span by class`. Either way, be sure to check for `null` since HTML Agility Pack returns `null` rather than empty collections (as you have discovered)!

Comment: @mjwills HTML Agility pack is so confusing... I took this line from the source code, not the dev tool, `<a name="&lpos=soccer-scoreboard-now:video:2" href="/video/clip?id=26736552">Maruti Suzuki Arena Presents ESPN.in Free Kick Episode 11</a>`, used this code `var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name='&lpos=soccer-scoreboard-now:video:2']"); lbl_geheel.Text = node.InnerText;` and got the same error.. This was the answer from the link that you've provided, but at the comments I saw the person who asked the question got the same error from that error.